# Cannot get to initialize empty list in CameLIGO

Tags: smart-contracts, ligo

I'm trying to write a smart contract in CameLIGO that looks like this

*parameters*
`"Hello world"`

*storage*
`[{ text = "Blob"; voters = ["tz1TKc3zQBMv7Rez77sX4JNdqMvG33LQrURk"]}]`

with the following code

```
type voters = address list option

type item = {
   text : string;
   voters : voters
}

type items_storage = item list

let add_item (new_text, items_storage : string * items_storage) : items_storage =
let new_item : item = {
    text = new_text;
    voters = (* Cannot get to initialize to an empty list *)
}
in
new_item :: items_storage 

let main (p, s : string * items_storage) : operation list * items_storage =
(([] : operation list), add_item(p, s))
```

I don't know how to initialize an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the voters to be optional then you need to initialize it with either the Some or None value constructors:

`voters = Some ([] : address list)`

or

`voters = (None : address list option)`

Comment: I have a Michelson error when trying your answers, I guess I might have an error in the storage : ```[...] At (unshown) location 5, value { "tz1TKc3zQBMv7Rez77sX4JNdqMvG33LQrURk" } is invalid for type option (list address). At (unshown) location 5, unexpected sequence, only a primitive can be used here. ``` But I manage to make it work with  : ```type voters = adress list``` and then ```voters = ([ ] : address list)``` but I don't know if it's the best solution.

Comment: @inpace If you want voters to be optional then you actually always need to wrap it in the appropriate type constructor. So when you set it in storage you'd use `voters = Some ([("tz1TKc3zQBMv7Rez77sX4JNdqMvG33LQrURk" : address)])`. There's nothing wrong with having it not be optional, just depends on your needs. It would certainly be easier to go with a regular `address list` and leave it empty when there are no voters.